# stuck in a revolving door of log-on screen and restart

Tags: nvidia, login-screen, acer, aspire

I had trouble loading a new version of Ubuntu. I gathered that it was someing to do with my graphics card, an Nvidia. Someone on here very kindly told be to use a nomodset kernel. This did work and I managed to do an install.

When the install was complete, the graphics were very poor and I cold not see all of the screen. I found a program that allowed me to select my graphics driver. I've done this an re-started. Now I'm stuck in a look of log-on screen and re-start. The graphics are better though.

I'm trying to install on an Acer Aspire Revo 3600? and there is Nvidia graphics chipset on it.

Can any one help??

Comment: My PC has an Intel Atom processor, if that helps?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what program you found, and exactly how you ran it?

Comment: It was a pre installed programme that scanned for proprietary drivers. It scanned and found that I wasn't using the Nvidia driver. Sorry, can't remember the name of it.

Comment: Is there a way of booting in safe mode like windows? I'm guessing that I need to update the driver, but I don't know how to do this. Can anyone help please?

Comment: can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: I've tried holding the left shift key down while booting up and it's still the same.